# Site has lower scores on desktop in Pagespeed Insights

Tags: nuxt.js, pagespeed-insights

I have a website based on nuxt SSR and I'm also using nuxt-speedkit with it. When I test my page speed with Pagespeed Insights, I get better results on mobile than on desktop, however it should be the other way as I know:

[image: mobile]

[image: desktop]

If I check the transfer sizes it seems like all the resources are duplicated on desktop compared to mobile, while the codebase is the same on both devices, only the images should be different. I also can see in dev tools network tab that the transferred resources are much smaller.

[image: mobile]

[image: desktop]

Why the transfer sizes are duplicated and what can I do to make Pagespeed Insights reflect the reality?

I have tried to reduce unused javascript but it doesn't help on the problem.

Comment: Pretty much answered to your own question: some things are loaded on desktop while they are mobile exclusive. Can be JS, CSS etc... Hard to say without some actual code.

Comment: I don't think this is the explanation because if you see the fonts for example, I have 6 font files, I also can see 6 on the network tab of the dev tools when the page is loading, but pagespeed insights shows 12 files.

Comment: Can you repeat it with a Lighthouse run in Chrome Dev Tools? There's also a huge increase in Third-Party requests. Are you sure it's not just more ads or the like that are able to be shown on the larger Desktop screensize and so it is actually loading more resources?

Comment: In Chrome Dev Tools the desktop report it seems to be correct: I have 98 performance score, 6 requests for fonts and 51 third-parties. The site is not running ads. If I check the requests on the network tab of dev tools, I still can see only 6 fonts, so this is correct.